# Get span text using bs4 with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table

What am I doing wrong here?

Problematic code:

```
page = requests.get(link).content
    soup = bs(page, "html.parser")
    
    element = soup.find('span', class_ = 'value')
    try:
      print(element)
    except:
      print('does not work..')
```

Well this are the highlighted lines for the specific block of message :

```
<section _ngcontent-tyn-c55="" class="tr-section">
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-tyn-c55="" class="body">
        <data-tile _ngcontent-tyn-c265="" trtitle="Current status" class="tr-gutter success light" _nghost-tyn-c85="">
            <div _ngcontent-tyn-c85="" role="heading" aria-level="3" class="title">Current status</div>
            <div _ngcontent-tyn-c85="" role="figure" class="value">
                <i _ngcontent-tyn-c85="" aria-label="figure icon" class="material-icons ng-star-inserted">check_circle</i>
                <!---->
                <span _ngcontent-tyn-c85="" aria-label="figure value">No unsafe content found</span>
            </div>
            <!---->
        </data-tile>
        <column-layout _ngcontent-tyn-c265="" _nghost-tyn-c54="">
            <!---->
            <div _ngcontent-tyn-c265="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                <h3 _ngcontent-tyn-c265="">Site info</h3>
                <p _ngcontent-tyn-c265="">This info was last updated on Feb 18, 2022.</p>
                <p _ngcontent-tyn-c265="">Site safety can change over time. Check back for updates.</p>
            </div>
            <!---->
        </column-layout>
    </div>
</section>
```

And an image with it:

[image: Block of the output message]

From this I want in my code to output the `span` '**No unsafe content found**'

How could I do this, I'd prefer directly the correct code, if possible, because that way I could understand it better.

Thank you,

RVZWN.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML isn't that clear. Here's a general way of doing it with the information you have given.

```py
# send request to page
res = requests.get(link)

# check if the response failed
if res.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    # Use select and select_one which allow you to use css selectors.
    message = soup.select_one(".body span").text
    print(message)
else:
    print("request to", link, "failed")
```

If you don't know how to use CSS selectors, there are some examples in https://devhints.io/css

Comment: Ok, I ll try that out, thanks for commenting! <3

Comment: Also, the HTML isn t that clear because the whole html source is huge and can t upload it here